# ansible playbook and role formatting syntax

Tags: ansible

teaching myself ansible. i'm trying to do a simple `ls -l` on a list of home directories.

###contents of my first playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - /home/admin/.ansible/vault/vault.yml
  roles:
    - list_home_dirs
```

###contents of my first role list_home_dirs

```
-  name: target home directories
   homedirs:
      - "/home/john"
      - "/home/jane"
   
-  name: listing contents of home directories
   shell: ls -l "{{ homedirs }}"
   ignore_errors: true
```

when i run my playbook with tasks on the role i get this:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>
The offending line appears to be:
- name: list content of home directories
  ^ here
```

i ran yamllint and online yml checkers. no issues with syntax mentioned.
can you please help me? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I would strongly recommend *against* jumping straight into roles and instead try to do this all in one playbook.  Roles have a very specific purpose, and that purpose only really becomes obvious after you've written several dozen playbooks.

Comment: A role is a list of valid Ansible tasks. `homedirs` is not the name of an ansible module; so your `target home directories` task is not a valid task. You may want to walk through some of the tutorials and examples available at https://docs.ansible.com and elsewhere.

Comment: Two entry points to knowledge on this subject: [ansible playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html) and [ansible roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html)